# How do I make an HTML button not reload the page

Tags: html, button, dom-events

I have a button (`<input type="submit">`). When it is clicked the page reloads. Since I have some jQuery `hide()` functions that are called on page load, this causes these elements to be hidden again. How do I make the button do nothing, so I can still add some action that occurs when the button is clicked but not reload the page.

Answer (score 331, accepted):

There is no need to use JS or jQuery.
to stop the page to reload, just specify the button type as 'button'.

If you don't specify the button type, the browser will automatically set it to 'reset' or 'submit' which causes the page to reload.

```
<button type='button'>submit</button>
```

Comment: This does work! It's a good alternative to `<input type='button' />`.

Comment: This works well, and particularly in the case of Chrome (for which the accepted answer doesn't)

Comment: Working on Chrome on Windows 10.  Yea!

Comment: This is great but it doesn't enforce required fields after you implement this.

Comment: The problem here though is it doesn't call the required or validation.

Answer (score 87):

Use either the [`<button>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) element or use an `<input type="button"/>`.

Comment: The <button> element by default causes a reload in chrome (at least).

Comment: you can still use form onsubmit event and return false if you still don't want to return

Comment: @AdamC This is not true.  No browser refreshes when you click on a <button> unless you explicitly add JavaScript to do it.

Comment: @Joe actually unfortunatelly it does :/ I need my webapp to work for IE8 and that reload is kinda annoying...

Comment: @pbeardshear It does if it is placed within a form. when `<button>` is placed outside a form the refresh does not occur!

Comment: I looked this up because my `<button>` elements were resubmitting my page when I didn't want them to.  Correct answer is Jafar Rasooli's below at least as of this date and where Chrome is concerned.  It is also correct that the button won't submit unless it's inside the form tag, as @Kevinvhengst mentions.  Apparently, the default button type is reset.

Comment: add `type="button"` to the `<button>` element in chrome and it doesn't refresh

Comment: `<button form=""></button>` prevents submission if it's inside a form (FF 59, Chrome 65). ([button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) at MDN)

Answer (score 44):

In HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
</form>
```

in order to avoid refresh at all "buttons", even with onclick assigned.

Comment: Should be correct answer. Using a button breaks the submit and require function of the form

Answer (score 15):

You could add a click handler on the button with jQuery and do return false.

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() { return false; });
```

or

```
$("form").submit(function() { return false; });
```

Comment: This doesnt work. Returning false in chrome, at least in latest versions, still causes refresh.

Comment: This is the only answer which actually worked for me. I just aded return false in my function and the refresh stopped in both safari and chrome.

Answer (score 14):

In HTML:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return false">
```

With jQuery, some similar variant, already mentioned.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a form that includes a submit button. Then use jQuery to prevent the default behavior of a form:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('submit', '#submit-form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    alert('page did not reload');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='submit-form'>
  <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also use JavaScript for that:

```
  let input = document.querySelector("input");
  input.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  })
```

Comment: this should've been the approved answer

Answer (score 5):

As stated in one of the comments (burried) above, this can be fixed by not placing the button tag inside the form tag. When the button is outside the form, the page does not refresh itself.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet, so I'm posting this as an answer.
Best way to avoid reload is how @user2868288 said: using the `onsubmit` on the `form` tag.

From all the other possibilities mentioned here, it's the only way which allows the new HTML5 browser data input validation to be triggered (`<button>` won't do it nor the jQuery/JS handlers) and allows your jQuery/AJAX dynamic info to be appended on the page.
For example:

```
<form id="frmData" onsubmit="return false">
 <input type="email" id="txtEmail" name="input_email" required="" placeholder="Enter a valid e-mail" spellcheck="false"/>
 <input type="tel" id="txtTel" name="input_tel" required="" placeholder="Enter your telephone number" spellcheck="false"/>
 <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Send Info"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
        var tel = $("#txtTel").val();
        var email = $("#txtEmail").val();
        $.post("scripts/contact.php", {
            tel1: tel,
            email1: email
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#lblEstatus').append(data); // Appends status
            if (data == "Received") {
                $("#btnSubmit").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // Disable doubleclickers.
            }
        })
        .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            $('#lblEstatus').append("Error. Try later."); 
        });
     });
   }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `event.preventDefault()` in the first line of your event function.

Buttons must be of the type `button` and contain `type="submit"` in the button html.

Answer (score 0):

Add a to the botton and input data-toggle="modal" like this

```
<a data-toggle="modal"><button type="submit">Edit Profile</button></a>
```