# How can I prevent refresh of page when button inside form is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue while using buttons inside form. I want that button to call function. It does, but with unwanted result that it refresh the page.

My simple code goes like this

```
<form method="POST">
    <button name="data" onclick="getData()">Click</button>
</form>
```

On clicking the button, the function gets called with page refreshed, which resets all my previous request which affects the current page which was result of the previous request.

What should I do to prevent the page refresh?

Comment: you have to specify the parameters, if you simple use window.location = window.location.href; it'll refresh the whole page & it'll resets all your previous requests. please check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make an HTML button not reload the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page)

Comment: @bunkdeath: Suck [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13262305/4509268) should be accepted.

Comment: @JadChahine sorry, I did not realised i have not accepted the answer, thanks for pointing this out. I was a beginner and did not know what I did or did not back then. But I wont be accepting the answer you mentioned, rather I will accept the one that helped me that time :)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Let `getData()` return false. This will fix it.

```
<form method="POST">
    <button name="data" onclick="return getData()">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Indeed. The `onclick` function has to return false, not `getData`.

Comment: That's what I ment, but okay, modified the answer so it's more clear.

Comment: you don't need to change the function - you can just use onclick="getData(); return false;"

Comment: `type="button"` is really the catch.

Comment: Why does this happen?
I would like to know more about this.

Answer (score 499):

Add `type="button"` to the button.

```html
<button name="data" type="button" onclick="getData()">Click</button>
```

The default value of `type` for a button is `submit`, which self posts the form in your case and makes it look like a refresh.

Comment: Except this prevents HTML5 form validation (such as for input of type="email").

Comment: You can also add `return false;` to the onclick: `onclick="getData(); return false;"`

Comment: This is the best option. While "return false" might work inline there is not such option, that I know of, when adding event listeners. Specifying the type="button" really saves the day.

Answer (score 30):

All you need to do is put a type tag and make the type button.

```html
<button id="btnId" type="button">Hide/Show</button>
```

That solves the issue

Comment: Can you elaborate and explain why?

Comment: default behavior of a button is of submit type when inside a form, on changing it to button type, post can be avoided

Comment: This is a great explanation, @Ganesh Kodiganti!

Answer (score 25):

The problem is that it triggers the form submission. If you make the `getData` function `return false` then it should stop the form from submitting.

Alternatively, you could also use the [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method of the event object:

```
function getData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: The click event that will be passed.

Comment: Except that (without further modifications) the event object won't be passed.

Comment: <button name="data" onclick="getData($event)">Click</button>

Answer (score 11):

### HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" id="myForm">
</form>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    doSomething();
});
```

Comment: $('.myForm) should be $('#myForm)

Answer (score 4):

If your button is default "button" make sure you explicity set the type attribute, otherwise the WebForm will treat it as submit by default.

**if you use js do like this**

```
<form method="POST">
   <button name="data"  type="button" id="btnData" onclick="getData()">Click</button>
</form> 

**If you use jquery use like this**


<form method="POST">
   <button name="data"  type="button" id="btnData">Click</button>
</form>




$('#btnData').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // Code goes here
getData(); // your onclick function call here

});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<form method="POST">
    <button name="data" onclick="getData()">Click</button>
</form>
```

instead of using button tag, use input tag. Like this,

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type = "button" name="data" onclick="getData()" value="Click">
</form>
```

Comment: but this did't create button as of `button type='button'`

Answer (score 2):

A javascript method to disable the button itself

```
document.getElementById("ID NAME").disabled = true;
```

Once all form fields have satisfied your criteria, you can re-enable the button

Using a Jquery will be something like this

```
$( "#ID NAME" ).prop( "disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is the best solution:

```
<form  method="post"> 
    <button  type="button" name="data" onclick="getData()">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

Note: My code is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

For any reason in Firefox even though I have `return false;` and `myform.preventDefault();` in the function, it refreshes the page after function runs. And I don't know if this is a good practice, but it works for me, I insert `javascript:this.preventDefault();` in the action attribute .

As I said, I tried all the other suggestions and they work fine in all browsers but Firefox, if you have the same issue, try adding the prevent event in the action attribute either `javascript:return false;` or `javascript:this.preventDefault();`. Do not try with `javascript:void(0);` which will break your code. Don't ask me why :-).

I don't think this is an elegant way to do it, but in my case I had no other choice.

Update:

If you received an error... after ajax is processed, then remove the attribute action and in the `onsubmit` attribute, execute your function followed by the false return:

`onsubmit="functionToRun(); return false;"`

I don't know why all this trouble with Firefox, but hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Return function is not working in all the cases. 
I tried this:

```
<button id="Reset" class="Button-class" onclick="return Reset()">Show result</button>
```

It didnt work for me.

I tried to return false inside the function and it worked for me.

```
function Reset()
{
    .
    .
    .
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. The problem is with the `onclick` function. There should not be any problem with the function `getData`. It worked by making the `onclick` function return false.

```
<form method="POST">
    <button name="data" onclick="getData(); return false">Click</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated on @JNDPNT answer, this way the function  (getData()) doesn't have to return false;

```
 <form method="POST">
    <button name="data" onclick="getData(); return false;">Click</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple issue I found is that if the function that you're trying to call is called `submit`, the form will be submitted either way.

You will need to rename the function for the page to not be reloaded

Answer (score -1):

Add `e.preventDefault();` in the starting of the function to be called when the button is clicked

Example:

```
    const signUp = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
```

The button code:

```
            <input
              type='submit'
              name='submit-btn'
              id='submit-btn'
              value='Sign Up'
              onClick={signUp}
            />
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use ajax and jquery to solve this problem:

```
<script>
    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "/urlpattern",
            type : "post",
            success : function(data) {
                alert("success");
            } 
        });
    }
</script>
<form method="POST">
    <button name="data" type="button" onclick="getData()">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This answer is overly complicated, let alone requiring an outside library to prevent the OP's issue where other, simpler, methods can be used.