# Javascript window.location.replace just reloads this page

Tags: javascript, html

It should be loading the index.html page with the uname param but for some reason it just keeps reloading this page over and over

I have tried every variation I can think of, to include looking at other working examples of my own and of other people.  This is not working because it hates me.

```
function loginLink() {

    var linkname = getURLParameter("uname");

    window.location.replace("http://www.walkwithpals.com/index.html?uname=" + linkname);
}
```

This is the html

```
 <button onclick="loginLink()">Already have an account and want to link to a friend?</button>
```

Here is the live site and the page in question [WalkWithPals](http://www.walkWithpals.com/register.html?uname=anythingjuststopreloadingthesamepage)

Comment: please don't use inline javascript, there are better and more appropriate ways to handle events. You'll make it a lot easier on yourself in the long run.

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevent refresh of page when button inside form clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803814/prevent-refresh-of-page-when-button-inside-form-clicked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the page from refreshing by making your form return `false` in order to not reload the page.

`<form onSubmit="foo();false;"></form>` if the function `foo()` doesn't alreay return false.

EDIT: Alternatively [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13262305/2644128) looks to be the answer.
By adding the attribute `type="button"` to your `button` element, this overrides the default `submit` behaviour.

Comment: -1 The issue is with the `loginLink()` function, which is not on a submit button. It wouldn't cause the form action to load.

Comment: sorry, i didn't know that `button` and `submit` fields don't have the same behavior when clicked. thx =)

Comment: @JivayI tried both of your answers and also a combination of them both. None of which worked

Comment: I edited my answer with a link i just found. Looks like the `button` element's default behavior is to be a `submit` button, and you can override that by changing your button's type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while you are returning false from your function, you aren't returning false within the event handler. You need to pass on the return value:

```
<button onclick="return loginLink()">...</button>
```

However, [as Stephen notes in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18435470#comment27087002_18435470), you really should move away from using inline event handlers. Since I see you've got jQuery included, if you make it easy to identify your button:

```
<button id="loginButton">...</button>
```

You can use jQuery to attach to it:

```
$('#loginButton').click(loginLink);
```

(such a script should go at the end of the `body` such that `loginButton` will exist at that point)