# Sharepoint 2013 redirects? after ajax call returns. Not sure why

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, sharepoint-2013, marionette

Hopefully I am able to explain this correctly.

I have a sharepoint 2013 page which I am using Marionette for the views, and a web api using MVC5 and EF6.

When you first get to the site you get 4 options and each one goes to a different view. In this case I am going to a view that allows me to search for attorneys. The view loads (I don't pull any data to begin with so it just loads with the search bar and the search button, along with a couple of other buttons), and I am then able to search.

I type in my search criteria and then click the search button. The click event fires appropriately, and my ajax call gets fired. The code below is my ajax call, which is contained within the collection that my view uses. Once I get a success returned it is supposed to load the data and then I can browse it. Instead what happens is I can see the call returns a success and the data is getting loaded into the view, and then all of a sudden it goes back to my main view, which has the 4 options as I described earlier. I know this works as I have tried this same code outside of sharepoint 2013 and the routing works properly. Is there something that Sharepoint 2013 doesn't like about backbone/Marionette routing? I don't get any errors when looking in the debugger in Chrome so I'm not sure what is going on. I have tried my other views that have button clicks similar to this scenario, but they all do the same thing.

As far as how I have this put into Sharepoint I resued the default.aspx that got generated by default and dumped my html code into it. I then setup the appropriate references to the js that I needed. Everything else appears to be working as I have been able to save data from my sharepoint page with the webapi calls successfully.

```
OcrtApplication.OcAttorneyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: OcrtApplication.OCAttorney,
    url: 'http://apiserver/OCAttorney',


    pageData: function (key, value, pageNum, perPage) {
        var self = this;

        var result = function (self, key, value, pageNum, perPage) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://apisurver/ocattorney/' + key + '/' + value + '/' + pageNum + '/' + perPage,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json",
                crossDomain:true,
                success: function (result) {
                    //alert(result);
                    self.reset(result);
                }
            });
        }
        result(self,key,value, pageNum, perPage );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found out what was going on. The stack overflow question below is what solved my problem. To sum it up short and sweet Sharepoint 2013 will treat a button element like an input for the form that surrounds the page. So in my case the default.aspx page housed my html inside it, but the master page for that contained a form, so the form was submitting when I clicked on any button without 
    type="button" 
Hopefully this will help others.

[prevent refresh of page when button inside form clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803814/prevent-refresh-of-page-when-button-inside-form-clicked)