# Cannot insert new HTML to BODY of the page

Tags: cordova, single-page-application, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm trying to implement simple "single page application" under Multi device hubrid apps. After pressing a button (and doing some ajax POST query), i'm trying to insert new HTML into 'body':

```
var finalHtml = '<header class="bar bar-nav">' +
    '<h1 class="title">Some text</h1>' +
'</header>' +
'<div class="content">' +
'</div>';
console.log('Rendering: ' + finalHtml);
$('body').html(finalHtml);
```

Nothing happens. I see (while debugging) that inner HTML of the body changes, but after all, page becomes as previous. I tried

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', finalHtml);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('appbody').innerHTML = finalHtml;
```

but it doesn't work.

What i'm missing?

**UPDATE:**
At the end of updating page, Javascript console output is:

`HTML1300: Navigation occurred 
File: index.html`

Looks like page is refreshed, by some reason. Why could it be? HTML part:

```
    <form>

        <input type="text" id="login" placeholder="Login" autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="try_login(document.getElementById('login').value, document.getElementById('pass').value, device.platform + ' ' + device.version);">
            Login
        </button>

    </form>
```

Javascript part:

```
function try_login(username, password, dev) {

var parameters = '';

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://some_url/Services/Authorize",
    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    processdata: true,
    success: function (msg) {
        renderView(DataView(msg));
    },
    error: function (obj, errorMessage) {
        renderView(LoginView() + ErrorView(errorMessage));
    },

});
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by- **inner HTML of the body changes, but after all, page becomes as previous**

Comment: While debugging (in VS 2013), i see, that `document.body.innerHTML` = my `finalHtml` (breakpoint after `$('body').html(finalHtml);`). I'm continuing execution, and see old page on screen (i'm using Ripple emulator).

Comment: Can you try console.log($('body').html()); after the insert?

Comment: console.log() shows my new html. But after that, Javascript console outputs that:
`HTML1300: Navigation occurred
File: index.html`
Why? May be, this is the reason?

Comment: No. That is the Developer Tool output... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180764(v=vs.85).aspx
Can you put more information/code?

Comment: Solved! Added `type="button"` to button on form. Solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803814/prevent-refresh-of-page-when-button-inside-form-clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Button in form refreshes the page, so I added `type="button"` to button on form. Solution found here: [prevent refresh of page when button inside form clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803814/prevent-refresh-of-page-when-button-inside-form-clicked)