# Interactive browser plot in Python 3.5 using bokeh/flexx pyscript

Tags: javascript, python, interactive, bokeh

***NOTE FROM MAINTAINERS:*** pyscript support is deprecated and will be removed in Bokeh 2.0

---

---

I'm currently learning Python and trying to make an interactive dashboard that runs on the browser. I'm using Bokeh for visualisation and flexx/pyscript for callback interactivity. The first goal is to make a button that filters a dataset. I tried using the slider example on

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/interaction.html

and I modified it to simply change the data by clicking a button (actual filtering would be step 2).

```
x = [1,2,3] # dummy data
y = [4,5,6] # dummy data

# output to static HTML file
# output_file("sample.html", title="sample")
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
plot = Figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)


def callback(source=source):
    data = source.get('data')
    f = cb_obj.get('value')
    x, y = data['x'], data['y']
    x = [0.9,0.8,0,7]
    y = [1,2,3]
    source.trigger('change')

button = Button(callback=CustomJS.from_py_func(callback))
button.on_click(source)

layout = vform(button, plot)

show(layout)
```

The page loads and I can click the buttons but a change in the plot is not triggered. Does you know how to modify this code so it triggers and actual change by using a bokeh button event handler? I have searched many websites but I cannot find a good example.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to actually update the data *on the data source*:

```
def callback(source=source):
    data = source.get('data')
    f = cb_obj.get('value')
    data['x'] = [0.9, 0.8, 0,7]
    data['y'] = [1,   2,   3  ]        
    source.trigger('change')
```

You code just creates *new* vars `x` and `y` and then immediately overwrites them. That doesn't actually update `.data` which is what needs to happen.

Comment: Thank you, just one more question.
When i press the button, the values changes accordingly, but then the plot immediately resets. I only want this to happen when I press the button a second time. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, you mean you don't want the data update to happen immediately? I think you could have the callback toggle some bool back and forth, and only call trigger on `true`. For instance `window.my_callback_flag` but there's probably a better idea than a global on `window`

Comment: When I click, my plot briefly shows the new data specified in the callback, but then the page reloads and immediately shows the original plot again.

Comment: It seems to be related to this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803814/prevent-refresh-of-page-when-button-inside-form-clicked. However, this page only provides a html solution

Comment: This button issue is fixed in current master, and will be included in the upcoming `0.12` release.

Comment: If you need a fix before then you could try installing a [Developer Preview Build](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/installation.html#developer-builds) but these are not guaranteed to be tested to the level of a stable release.