# I need to show a hidden Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So, my page starts with a hidden `iframe`, that I have to show after submitting my form. While it seems pretty easy, I have absolutely no idea why it isn't working, and I'd be happy if you could help.
Here is the code for the `iframe`:

```
        <iframe src="" name= "UpdIframe" id= "UpdIframe" style="display:none"> </iframe>
```

And here is the JS function that I'm using to hide and show it.

```
<script>
function submitFrame(){
document.getElementById('UpdIframe').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

This function actually does more things, but I believe they are irrelevant to the question, so I opted to take it out. And finally, here's the button calling the `Onclick` Event:

```
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="botao" type="submit" value="Update" onclick="submitFrame()" style="width: 120px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I think when you are submitting  form the page gets reload in that case it won't capture the JS function that you have made.. Try to submit form with ajax..

Comment: you should try something like : after submit in the other page result display the iframe , no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is refreshing the page when you submit it. Change `type=submit` to `type=button`.

```
<input class="botao" type="button" value="Update" onclick="submitFrame()" style="width: 120px;">
```

---

```
<script>
    function submitFrame(){
        document.getElementById('UpdIframe').style.display = "block";
        // Also handle your form submission/POST here
    }
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q3ceto1n/

References:

[Form Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803814/prevent-refresh-of-page-when-button-inside-form-clicked)

[Handle POST outside form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Answer (score 0):

If your function also submits form data you can modify

```
<input class="botao" type="submit" value="Update" onclick="submitFrame(event)" style="width: 120px;">
```

and

```
<script>
function submitFrame(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('UpdIframe').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```