# Why does AJAX + GET refresh page?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, dom, event-handling

I try a lot of ways to prevent this, but nothing works which is puzzling.

This is the route for get.

```
router.get('/some', function(request, response, next) {
    console.log('> info: some');
    response.send({"hello": "world"});
}
```

This is the AJAX part hooked to `onClick` of an element.

```
  on_click = function(event) {
    //console.log(event.href);

    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if (target.nodeType == 3)
        target = target.parentNode;

    target.preventDefault();
    target.stopPropagation();
    target.stopImmediatePropagation();

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

   $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: target.href,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        })
        .done(function(received_data) {
            $('.container').html('<h1>hello here</h1>');
            return false;
        })
        .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            return false;
        });
   return false;
}
```

I expect to see `"hello here"`. It works for a small test program. But when I add to my development code, it always show a white page with the JSON string of hello world.

So far I have tried the followings.

- send string instead of JSON object directly
- change `dataType` to `text`
- set `processData` to `false`
- `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation`, `stopImmediatePropagation`

I apology that I cannot upload the development code, but any guess why it is so stubborn to refresh the page?

BTW, for POST, it works perfectly.

This is the related element:

```
<a href="/some" onClick="on_click(this); return false;"></a>
```

Comment: *"...hooked to onClick of an element."* - What kind of element? Something causing a form submit, perhaps? Would help to see the HTML and the code surrounding the `$.ajax`.

Comment: I imagine OP has something like `<form action="/some"><button>I have a click event handler</button></form>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent refresh of page when button inside form clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803814/prevent-refresh-of-page-when-button-inside-form-clicked)

Comment: From what you describe, it's *not* refreshing the page, but navigating to a new page. Since none of your code would cause the browser to navigate to `/some`, it must be that whatever you are clicking on (form? link?) is independently set up to perform a normal navigation. (Or else you have other code in your click handler, or another handler attached to the thing being clicked.)

Comment: @TylerRoper, I supply the info of element, please check.

Comment: Okay, based on that edit: you have a link set to navigate to `/some` and don't do anything to stop the navigation. (`return false` only stops the default behavior when you do it in a jQuery `.on` event handler.) `e.preventDefault()` should do it, but you must call it inside the synchronous code of the click handler, not inside the `.done` callback. Can you show a complete example that includes the definition of `on_click` and shows how you tried to use `preventDefault`?

Comment: @apsillers, updated.

Comment: You're calling `preventDefault` on `this` (the `<a>` element) instead of the event object. I think you need to call `on_click(event)` not `on_click(this)`

Comment: @apsillers, confirmed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
response.send({"hello": "world"});
```

Try

```
response.json({"hello": "world"});
```

Express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

Using `response.json()` correctly sets the `Content-Type` header in the response.

Comment: Good advice but probably not the problem OP currently has

Comment: While this is unquestionably good practice, it is definitely not related to the problem the OP describes here.