# Axios not returning response in Vuex action

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm trying to `GET` a response from an API endpoint using Axios, but nothing is coming back.

I've tried putting the Axios call in the component and in the Vuex store, but no luck so far.

store.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    similarTitles: []
  },
  mutations: {
    SIMILAR_TITLES_LIST(state, similarTitles) {
      state.similarTitles = similarTitles;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async getSimilarTitles({ commit }, payload) {
      console.log("axios begin"); // this shows briefly
      await axios
        .get(
          `https://tastedive.com/api/similar?q=${payload}&type=books&info=1&k=${process.env.VUE_APP_TASTE_DIVE_API_KEY}`
        )
        .then(data => {
          console.log("did i get here?"); // this never shows
          console.log(data.Similar.Results); // or this
          commit("SIMILAR_TITLES_LIST", data.Similar.Results); // not surprising that this doesn't put info into state
        });
      console.log("axios end"); // this shows briefly
    }
  }
});
```

Recommender.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="recommender">
    <h1>Oscar's Book Recommendations!</h1>
    <form class="findTitle">
      <label for="enjoyedTitle">What's the name of a book you liked?</label>
      <br />
      <input type="text" id="enjoyedTitle" v-model="enjoyedTitle" />
      <br />
      <button @click="findSimilarTitles">Find a new book!</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Recommender",
  data() {
    return {
      enjoyedTitle: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async findSimilarTitles() {
      await this.$store.dispatch("getSimilarTitles", this.enjoyedTitle);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.recommender {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;

  form {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-self: center;
    width: 21em;

    button {
      align-self: center;
      width: 10em;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

This is failing silently. The `console.log` statements before and after the Axios call briefly show in the console, but then the component resets and all console statements disappear. The `console.log` statements inside the Axios call never show. I know this can work somehow, otherwise the internet won't do anything. Can somebody point out what I'm not seeing?

Appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: Your form is probably submitting normally. Try `<button type="button" @click="findSimilarTitles">` or my personal favourite, `<form @submit.prevent="findSimilarTitles">`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent refresh of page when button inside form clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803814/prevent-refresh-of-page-when-button-inside-form-clicked)

Comment: remove `@click="findSimilarTitles"` from button and add `@subimt="findSimilarTitles"` on the `form` element

Comment: do you have an exception? have you tried putting a `.catch(e =>  alert(e) )` block?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. i used phil's suggestion ```<button type="button" @click="findSimilarTitles">```. i'm now getting into the ```.catch``` block that both ravi kumar and saleem suggested. my main error now is a cors issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should catch like

```
async getSimilarTitles({ commit }, payload) {
  console.log("axios begin"); // this shows briefly
  await axios
    .get(
      `https://tastedive.com/api/similar?q=${payload}&type=books&info=1&k=${process.env.VUE_APP_TASTE_DIVE_API_KEY}`
    )
    .then(data => {
      console.log("did i get here?"); // this never shows
      console.log(data.Similar.Results); // or this
      commit("SIMILAR_TITLES_LIST", data.Similar.Results); // not surprising that this doesn't put info into state
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Call Failed!'); 
        console.log(err);
    });
  console.log("axios end"); // this shows briefly
}
```

}

Comment: thanks! i added a catch block and now i know i'm having a cors issue.