# Vue Front End Stops Functioning Properly When Using in Nodejs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I am working on a project and decided to use Vuejs to create a dynamic form. After successfully putting this form together, I copied the code to begin using in a Nodejs project, however, it no longer creates new form fields. Instead, for a brief second it creates a form field and then it immediately disappears. I am confused as to why it's doing this, any suggestions?

```
// Modules required to run the application
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');

// Creates an express application
var app = express();

// Config
const db = require('./config/keys').MongoURI; // Database Config
require('./config/passport')(passport); // Passport Config

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }) 
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected...')) 
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Accepts a parameter from the 'ENVIROMENT' for what 
// port to listen on and sends to sever
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Sets up view engine (using 'ejs')
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Bodyparser - urlencoded() is used to recognize incoming Request Object as strings or arrays
// Specifically to help with POST and PUT Requrests
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // 'extended' has to do with whether or not a nested object can be used ('false' means it cannot)

// Express session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Connect flash
app.use(flash());

// Allows express app access to CSS and JavaScript files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Allows for access to user information after login
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    next();
});

// Route Files
app.use('/', require('./routes/index')); // Module containing basic paths for application
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users')); // Module containing paths for user login and registration
app.use('/recipes', require('./routes/recipes')); // Module containing paths for user user recipes

app.listen(app.get("port"), function(){
    console.log(`Listening to server on port ${app.get("port")}...`);
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Homemade</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="newRecipeContainer">
        <form action="/recipes/createRecipe" method="POST">
            <div class="recipeNameContainer">
                <label class="recipeNameLabel">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="recipeName">
            </div>

            <div class="directionsContainer">
                <button class="addDirectionButton" @click="addDirectionForm">Add Another Direction</button>
        
                <div class="allDirections" v-for="(direction, index) in directions">
                    <button class="deleteDirectionButton" @click="deleteDirectionForm(index)">Delete Direction</button>
        
                    <label class="direction">{{ index }}.)</label>
                    <input type="text" name="directions" v-model="direction.direction">
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="createRecipeButton" type="submit">Create Recipe</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="/controls/newRecipeControl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '.directionsContainer',
    data: {
        directions: [
            {
                direction: ''
            }
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        addDirectionForm: function(){
            this.directions.push({
                direction: ''
            })
        },

        deleteDirectionForm: function(index){
            if(index != 0)
                this.directions.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }
})
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Add `type="button"` to your Vue buttons. The default is `type="submit"` so they're submitting your form

Comment: From the linked duplicate, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13262305/283366)