# uploading a file with fetch() works but then skips both success *and* error paths

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I'm uploading a file with fetch(), and when the upload is finished, call fetch() again to add or amend a MariaDB row.
When I upload a file and *add* the row, it works.
When I upload a file and *amend* the row, the file is uploaded but the 2nd fetch() is not called, and the page just reloads.

This is the code that does both tasks

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);

fetch('upload.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: form_data
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(data => {
    console.log("data in fileUpload:", data);
    itemUpdate ( toPostObj, data )    })  // add or amend the row data
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
})
```

This seems so self-contained in that scrap of code that I can't see how it can bypass both console logs.  Whether the file upload terminates correctly or with an error, it has to write to the console.  Or so I thought.

When adding a file and row, it does so. The console shows

```
"data in fileUpload: The file 5.jpg has been uploaded."
```

But when adding a file and *amending* a row, it uploads the file, and reloads the page, showing this:

```
Navigated to http://192.168.0.104/t3/journal.html?chooseFile2=6.jpg&fileDisp=keepFile
```

Add and amend use different forms on the web page.  They both use type=button, not <input type="submit"> and pressing a button triggers the appropriate event listener.  itemUpdate() does another fetch() to access the database and is never executed.  It starts with a console.log statement which never appears.

upload.php writes to a log file on the server and the debug logging in that has messages that confirm this operated as expected. The file is uploaded. Finally, the apache2 php error.log is empty.

I have access to the server.

I've been looking at this all day.  Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Clicking the button probably submits the form it's attached to, **refreshing the page**…!? You need to `preventDefault` if you're handling a form submission via Javascript…

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it. Some how I'd got it linked in my mind to avoiding type=submit in the HTML.

Please make this an answer so I can flag it as such.

Comment: It has been suggested that this is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803814/prevent-refresh-of-page-when-button-inside-form-clicked
but that assumes that I knew that the problem lay with the button.  I didn't, and to me the problem seemed to be understanding how a fetch() could bypass its success and error logic.

I agree the answer is the same, but I started with a different point of ignorance, and if I'd seen that question, I wouldn't have seen that it was relevant.