# Can't use user inputs from options and text fields in a function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, input

I'm pretty new to programming, I'm trying to get the user input of the options from "province" and the value from "income" and use it in the js function below, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

```html
<div class="taxform">
  <form>
    <label for="province">Please select your province from the list below: </label>
    <select id="province" name="province">
      <option value="0">Select option</option>
      <option value="1">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
      <option value="2">Prince Edward Island</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <form>
    <label for="income">Please enter your annual income: </label>
    <input type="number" value="" id="income" name="income">
    <br> <br>
    <button onclick="calculate(document.getElementById('province').value,document.getElementById('income').value)">Calculate</button>
  </form>
```

```js
function calculate() {
  var percentage;
  var province = province(document.taxform.province.value);
  var income = income(document.taxform.income.value);
  if province = 1 {
    percentage = 20;
  }
  else if province = 2 {
    percentage = 30;
  }
  var res = (income - ((percentage / 100) * income));
  alert(res);
}
```

Comment: You're passing two parameters to `calculate()` but it doesn't accept any. You're also calling two undefined functions... `province()` and `income()`. Finally, add `type="button"` to your `<button>` to prevent it from [submitting the form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7803814/283366)

Comment: I think you should remove form tag and edit scripts   var province = document.getElementById('province').value;
  var income = document.getElementById('income').value;

Comment: @Phil thanks a lot for pointing out my basic mistakes, it's working as intended now