# page is refreshing after function is called (javascript)

Tags: javascript, forms, function

i need to show input value on page. when i press submit button value shows for a moment and then page refreshes immediately. i want the page not to resresh and show value. Also i would like to know why page is refreshing after submit button. Thank in advance!
HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="myFunc()">
    </form>
    <p id="show_name"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function myFunc(){
    const obj = {
        name : document.getElementById("name").value
    }
    document.getElementById("show_name").innerHTML = obj.name;
}
```

i already have tried `event.preventDefault()` and it worked but i would like to know if there are another ways or i just have mistakes in code.

Comment: you could remove the form element altogether and change the input from type=submit to type=button

Comment: You are submitting the form when you click the button "Send". This refreshes the page. You need to prevent that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted

Comment: Agree with Matt here, A form submit always trigger a new request, unless you prevent it bubbling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent refresh of page when button inside form is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803814/how-can-i-prevent-refresh-of-page-when-button-inside-form-is-clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use button element instead of input element

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunc()">Send</button>
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="Send"/>
```

and use e.preventDefault() in your Js code

When you set type="button", the button is considered a regular button and won't trigger the form submission by default

Comment: Thanks! i put button tag outside the form tag and page isnt refreshing.

Comment: **Hope it Helped**

Answer (score 1):

If you use `event.preventDefault()` without passing any event this means you are using the `event` directly from the window object which is currently deprecated. It's still supported by different browsers but I'd recommend to not rely on [mozilla - more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event).

So it's recommended to pass the `event` into the event handler function.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text">

        <!-- here: myFunc(event) -->
        <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="myFunc(event)">
    </form>
    <p id="show_name"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
/// add [event]
function myFunc(event){
    event.preventDefault()

    const obj = {
        name : document.getElementById("name").value
    }
    document.getElementById("show_name").innerHTML = obj.name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Submit button when click on it send a http request to the server and this protocol knows that for this type of request, the answer gived must refresh the web page before appear

HTTP, the Hypertext Transfer Protocol, is the foundation of the web, and it is what allows web browsers to communicate with web servers to request and receive web pages.

So, to stop page to refresh like you said, using the event.preventDefault() was good.