# Why .on('submit') redirects to another page in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a submit event:

```
    $('#id').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clicksCounter++;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: id,
            clickCounter: clicksCounter > 1
        },
        url: 'url',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response) {
                $('#modal').modal('hide');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But somehow it's redirecting me to another page instead of going to the function. I thought that `e.preventDefault()` will help, but it didn't. Also tried `location.reload()`, but it didn't helped either.

Could someone explain me why? Thank you for your time

Comment: Try to `return false;`.

Comment: What's the HTML of `#id`?

Comment: @Cerbrus it's the modal submission button

Comment: That's not what I asked. What is the button's HTML?

Comment: If `#id` is a submit button, the problem might be in your `form` tag. Try to remove `action` attribute out of the `form`.

Comment: Bind `submit` event  handler with `form` element not `button`

Comment: Or what HTML form is it submitting (i.e., what is the button related to)

Comment: Plz post your html for a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you dont need the form you can also use a button type input instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to prevent page refresh on button click in html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072120/how-to-prevent-page-refresh-on-button-click-in-html5)

Comment: Add `console.log('something');` before, in the middle, and after the code you pasted so you can see if it's being called. Also post your HTML so we can check you are using the correct ID.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are capturing the submit event on the wrong element. Instead of the submit button, it should be the ID of the form that is being submitted. E.g.

```
$('#myModalForm').on('submit', function(e) {
```