# call jQuery on submit event reload the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Sorry but, I am getting crazy with this problem. Each time I call jQuery it reloads my page.

**HTML file:**

```
<body>
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' id="form_id">
---- some inputs here ------
<input type='submit' value='Basic search'>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#form_id', function() {
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'phpfile.php',
            data : data,
            success :  function(data)
            {$(".result").html(data);} //result is div that i want display result in it

        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

**Edit 1:**
I use `<input type ='button'>` insted of `<input type = 'submit'>` but it does not works.
And I add

```
$(document).on('click', '#search_button', function(e)
 {
 e.preventDefault();
```

But, it does not works!

**Edit 2:**
The error msg in console:
Form contains enctype=multipart/form-data, but does not contain method=post.  Submitting normally with method=GET and no enctype instead.

A form was submitted in the windows-1252 encoding which cannot encode all Unicode characters, so user input may get corrupted. To avoid this problem, the page should be changed so that the form is submitted in the UTF-8 encoding either by changing the encoding of the page itself to UTF-8 or by specifying accept-charset=utf-8 on the form element.

Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form.  The file will not be sent.

mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Add a `console.log()` statement to the function, to check whether it's being executed.

Comment: `<input type='submit'>` reloads the page. That's what it does pretty much. You want to use another element like `<button>`. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page

Comment: @Anant all thing you mention is there but, i just wrote what i used in the post. I recently add e.preventDefault() but it does not work.

Comment: @BoltKey Do you mean <input type = 'button' >?

Comment: @Anant actually, No. I add <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script> but it show me an error in the platform.

Comment: @Barmar hot to use console.log()?

Comment: @Reem `console.log("in the submit function")` will display the message in the Javascript console. This is really basic, it should be in any Javascript tutorial.

Comment: @Barmar console.log("in the submit function") did not displayed in the console

Comment: Then something is preventing your event binding from working.  I don't see anything obvious in the question, it must be something you haven't posted.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104332/discussion-between-reem-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by replace $ with jQuery

```
jQuery.ajax insted of $.ajax
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `<input type='submit'>`, because that reloads the page by default. Use `<button>` instead.

```
<button id='search_button'>Basic search</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#search_button', function() {
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'phpfile.php',
            data : data,
            success :  function(data)
            {$(".result").html(data);} //result is div that i want display result in it

        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It does not work! also I add e.preventDefault() but it reload the page

Comment: `return false` from a jQuery event handler is equivalent to `e.preventDefault()`. This should prevent the default submission.