# Angular ajax submit form

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I am having problem with ajax submit form with angular, when i click submit my entire page is reloaded?

Where can be the problem, here is my code

```
/*
Create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
*/

// resource2Controller
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("aluPlanetApp").controller('resource2Controller', resource2Controller);
    resource2Controller.$inject = ['$scope'];
    resource2Controller.$inject = ['$http'];

    function resource2Controller($scope, $http) {

        activate();

        function activate() {

            $scope.title = 'Contact';
            $scope.id = '2';
            $scope.result = 'hidden'
            $scope.resultMessage;
            $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
            $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
            $scope.submit = function (contactform) {
                $scope.submitted = true;
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                if (contactform.$valid) {
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'contact-form.php',
                        data: $.param($scope.formData),  //param method from jQuery
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
                    }).success(function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                            $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                            $scope.result = 'bg-success';
                        } else {
                            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                            $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                            $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                    $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed <img src="http://www.chaosm.net/blog/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_sad.gif" alt=":(" class="wp-smiley">  Please fill out all the fields.';
                    $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

And **contact-form.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['inputName']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) && isset($_POST['inputSubject']) && isset($_POST['inputMessage'])) {

    //check if any of the inputs are empty
    if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputSubject']) || empty($_POST['inputMessage'])) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    //create an instance of PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['inputName'];
    $mail->AddAddress('something@test.com'); //recipient 
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
    $mail->Body = "Name: " . $_POST['inputName'] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputMessage']);

    if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
        $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
    }

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
    echo json_encode($data);

} else {

    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-controller="resource2Controller" class="panel-body">
                    <form ng-submit="submit(contactform)" name="contactform" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputName.$invalid && submitted }">
                            <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input ng-model="formData.inputName" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputEmail.$invalid && submitted }">
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input ng-model="formData.inputEmail" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputSubject.$invalid && submitted }">
                            <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input ng-model="formData.inputSubject" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputMessage.$invalid && submitted }">
                            <label for="inputMessage" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <textarea ng-model="formData.inputMessage" class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..." required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="submitButtonDisabled">
                                    Send Message
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <p ng-class="result" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0;">{{ resultMessage }}</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you using `ng-submit=""` directive?

Comment: I am using angular 1.5.6 when i submit form got error in angular something like line 1872??

Comment: I am using angular 1.5.6 when i submit form got error in angular something like line 11821??

Comment: Sorry, I finished reading angular's source code on line 781 :-) But seriously, you should dig into the error that occures.

Answer (score 0):

Mhh I belive that maybe your problem is in the HTML which I can't see right now so make sure that you are not using the submit button. I mean Instead of `<input type="submit"...` use `<input type="button"...`Here is a reference [How do I make an HTML button not reload the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page)

Comment: I am using angular 1.5.6 when i submit form got error in angular something like line 11821??

Comment: I'm wondering if at this time you resolved the problem. By the way did you try with another version of angular?

Answer (score 0):

On your HTML, you call your controller ContactController while at the Angular side you call it resource2Controller. Those two should match or Angular doesn't know what to do.