# <form/> tag causes refresh page

Tags: javascript, html

When I click the submit button, it causes refresh page! But after I delete the  tag, it works well.What,s the problem of this, how can I avoid this problem without deleting the  tag, the codes are as follows:

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function password() {
 var word = document.getElementById("password");
 var load = document.getElementById("display");
 if(word.type=="password"){
  word.type = "text";
  load.value = "hidden"
 }
 else{
  word.type = "password";
  load.value = "display";
 }
 }
</script>
<form>
<input type="password" name="password" value="password" id="password" />
<input type="submit" name="display" onclick="password()" value="display" id="display"/>
</form>
```

Comment: delete the <form> tag

Comment: What is it that you think the `<form>` tag is *supposed* to do?

Comment: please check these links  http://stackoverflow.com/q/19454310/6572922

http://stackoverflow.com/q/1878264/6572922

Comment: On `password()` just do a `return false`

Comment: The language attribute on the script tag is deprecated and the type defaults to JavaScript, thus you can just write `<script>` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change type input from `submit`  to `button`

```
<input type="button" name="display" onclick="password()" value="display" id="display"/>
```

`<input type="button" />` buttons will not submit a form - they don't do anything by default. They're generally used in conjunction with JavaScript as part of an AJAX application.

`<input type="submit">` buttons will submit the form they are in when the user clicks on them, unless you specify otherwise with JavaScript.

**Or**

You can stop submit form with javascript

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Op is not tagged jQuery and not shown to be using it. Providing library dependent answers is therefore not appropriate...especially when you don't even qualify it as being such

Comment: For the second option with vanilla JS: `var elem = document.getElementbyId('display'); elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); password(); });`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="javascript:return false">
```

to prevent form submit.

Of course, when you need to submit the form (for example, after you have done validating, sanitizing your form), you have to do this:

```
document.querySelector('form').submit()
```

Comment: The "javascript:" protocol prefix on your `onsubmit` attribute value is not necessary, all `on_____` attributes expect the content to be JavaScript code