# How to restrict page reloading after non-submitting button click on form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make a button on an HTML form add elements to the form:

```js
function createRow(){
    var row = document.createElement('div');
    var input=document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute("type", "Textbox");
    var time=document.createElement('input');
    time.setAttribute("type", "Textbox");
    row.appendChild(input);
    row.appendChild(time);
    return row;
}
function addRow(){
    console.log("z");
    var routes = document.getElementById("routes");
    routes.appendChild(createRow());
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="routes">
    <button onclick="addRow()">+</button>
</form>
```

But on each button click the page reloads with a question mark added to url.
I've found a pair of ideas:

1. preventDefault(e)
2. return false

but none worked.

Please tell me what shall I fix? Also there are some conditions:

1. This is not the submit button, which will be added later
2. It's required to keep it as simple as possible, the interface is not main focus of project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an HTML button not reload the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of `button` is to submit.  Specify the `type=button` and it will override this default behavior.

`<button type="button" onclick="addRow()">+</button>`

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` function should `return false`. Also `addRow()` needs to `return false`:

```
<form id="routes">
   <button onclick="return addRow()">+</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is example of using preventDefault on event listener.

```js
 function createRow(){
    var row = document.createElement('div');
    var input=document.createElement('input');
    var time=document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute("type", "Textbox");
    time.setAttribute("type", "Textbox");
    row.appendChild(input);
    row.appendChild(time);
    return row;
}

function addRow(){
    document.getElementById("routes").appendChild(createRow());
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  addRow();
});
```

```html
<form id="routes">
    <button>+</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of a form an HTML5 button element has a default type of submit. If you give it a type of "button" everything works fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="routes">
     <div><button type="button" onclick="addRow()">+</button></div>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function createRow(){
         var row = document.createElement('div');
         var input=document.createElement('input');
         input.setAttribute("type", "Textbox");
         var time=document.createElement('input');
         time.setAttribute("type", "Textbox");
         row.appendChild(input);
         row.appendChild(time);
         console.log(row);
         return row;
     }
     function addRow(){
         console.log("z");
         var routes = document.getElementById("routes");
         routes.appendChild(createRow());
         return false;
     }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give button a `id` and put `preventDefault` inside `$(document).ready(..)` function

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
 
  $( "#routes_button" ).click(function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();  
  });
 });
 
 function createRow(){
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        var input=document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute("type", "Textbox");
        var time=document.createElement('input');
        time.setAttribute("type", "Textbox");
        row.appendChild(input);
        row.appendChild(time);
        return row;
    }
    function addRow(){
        console.log("z");
        var routes = document.getElementById("routes");
        routes.appendChild(createRow());
        return false;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="routes">
        <button id="routes_button" onclick="addRow()">+</button>
    </form>
```