# DOM manipulation practice on JavaScript --- help pls

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

I am currently learning JavaScript on my own and trying to practise DOM manipulation with a simple scheduler application which accepts information in a form (taking in the date, name, and event description), and thereafter inserts the form responses into a calendar corresponding to the day.

I basically used a for loop to loop through the entire calendar to find the date corresponding to the one chosen in the form, and if it is equal, then the input values will be slotted under the date.

(For the moment let's just assume the calendar can only hold October 2018 dates, for simplicity sake.)

Thanks a lot for the help!!

```js
const dateInput = document.getElementById('date');
const nameInput = document.getElementById('who');
const remarksInput = document.getElementById('remarks');
const eventAdderButton = document.getElementById('event-adder-button');
const calendar = document.getElementsByClassName('days');

eventAdderButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const date = dateInput.value.slice(3,5);
  for (let i = 0; i < calendar.length; i += 1) {
    const calendardays = calendar[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (let j = 0; j < calendardays.length; j += 1) {
      if (calendardays[j].textContent == date) {
        const newEvent = document.createElement('p');
        newEvent.textContent = remarksInput.value + nameInput.value;
        calendardays[j].innerHTML = "<p>" + calendardays[j] + "</p>" + newEvent.innerHTML;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  color: inherit;
}

.intro-wrapper {
  background-color: #45d1a0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}



#intro {
  background-color: #45d1a0;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Chelsea Market";
  border-style: double;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: thick;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;

}


.form-wrapper {
  background-color: #d15545;
  font-family: "Chelsea Market";
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

.form-start {
  color: white;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: thick;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

label, #event-adder-button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}


#date, #who, #remarks {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.calendar-wrapper {
  background-color: #03f;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Chelsea Market";
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

ul {list-style-type: none;}

/* Month header */
.month {
    padding: 25px 25px;
    background: #1abc9c;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Month list */
.month ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.month ul li {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

/* Previous button inside month header */
.month .prev {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* Next button */
.month .next {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* calendar table */

.calendar-table {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Weekdays (Mon-Sun) */
.weekdays {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color:#ddd;
    width: 100%;
}

.weekdays th {
    width: 10%;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid;
}

/* Days (1-31) */
.days {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0;
}

.days td {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #777;
    border: solid;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;

}

/* Highlight the "current" day */
.days td .active {
    padding: 3px;
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: white !important
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My Calendar Application</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chelsea+Market' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Banner -->
    <div class="intro-wrapper">
      <section id="intro">
        <p></p>

        <h2>Manage your Schedule</h2>
        <p>Add. Share. And Enjoy!</p>
      </section>
    </div>

    <div class="form-wrapper">
      <section id="one">
        <div class="form-start">
          <header>
            <h2>Add an Event</h2>
          </header>
          <form method="post" action="#">
            <div>
              <label for="date">Date</label>
              <br>
              <input name="date" id="date" type="date">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
              <label for="who">With Whom?</label>
              <br>
              <input name="who" id="who" type="text">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
              <label for="remarks">Remarks</label>
              <br>
              <textarea name="remarks" id="remarks" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input value="Add Event" type="submit" id="event-adder-button"></li>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>

    <!--end of Form-->

    <!-- Calendar -->
    <section class="calendar-wrapper">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2>Calendar</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="month">
        <ul>
          <li class="prev">&#10094;</li>
          <li class="next">&#10095;</li>
          <li>October<br><span style="font-size:18px">2018</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <table class="calendar-table">
          <tr class="weekdays">
            <th>Mo</th>
            <th>Tu</th>
            <th>We</th>
            <th>Th</th>
            <th>Fr</th>
            <th>Sa</th>
            <th>Su</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="days">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="days">
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td><span class="active">10</span></td>>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="days">
            <td>15</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>21</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="days">
            <td>22</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>28</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="days">
            <td>29</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>31</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>


    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're running into?

Comment: i try to add an event by filling in the form but nothing turns up. clicking the add event button immediately brings me back up to the top of the page. Thanks for replying btw!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an HTML button not reload the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page)

Comment: And `dateInput.value` will [always look like `yyyy-mm-dd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value).

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple problems in your code:

1. You were not stopping the form to submit, which caused the page to reset (form included), you need to use preventDefault() on the form submit event.
2. You were not comparing the day's html element to the date string correctly, the split function didn't work as expected, which should be changed to a `date.value.split('-') to get an array with`[yyyy-mm-dd]` format.
3. As days are passed as a `dd` format string, all == comparisons for < 10 day number will fail (e.g.: `02 == 2 === false`), fixed it with `parseInt()`
4. After the above issues are solved, you'll append the new data into each day's table, which resulted in modifying the `textContent` with the newly added element, hence all further comparisons will fail. (e.g.: With whom? 'me', Remarks? 'Okay', date: 10/02/2018, *resulted in* `2meOkay` for textContent on that table element.

Below I provide a functional html page that you can look into for further detail:

*might have been cleaner to strip the css, but this works best for a copy-test scenario.*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Calendar Application</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chelsea+Market' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        h2 {
            color: inherit;
        }

        .intro-wrapper {
            background-color: #45d1a0;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 10px;
        }



        #intro {
            background-color: #45d1a0;
            color: white;
            font-family: "Chelsea Market";
            border-style: double;
            border-color: white;
            border-width: thick;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 10px;

        }


        .form-wrapper {
            background-color: #d15545;
            font-family: "Chelsea Market";
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 10px;
        }

        .form-start {
            color: white;
            border-style: double;
            border-color: white;
            border-width: thick;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 10px;
        }

        label,
        #event-adder-button {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }


        #date,
        #who,
        #remarks {
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .calendar-wrapper {
            background-color: #03f;
            color: white;
            font-family: "Chelsea Market";
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 10px;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        /* Month header */

        .month {
            padding: 25px 25px;
            background: #1abc9c;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /* Month list */

        .month ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .month ul li {
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
        }

        /* Previous button inside month header */

        .month .prev {
            float: left;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        /* Next button */

        .month .next {
            float: right;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        /* calendar table */

        .calendar-table {
            width: 100%;
        }


        /* Weekdays (Mon-Sun) */

        .weekdays {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 10px 0;
            background-color: #ddd;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .weekdays th {
            width: 10%;
            color: #666;
            text-align: center;
            border: solid;
        }

        /* Days (1-31) */

        .days {
            padding: 10px 0;
            background: #eee;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .days td {
            width: 10%;
            height: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #777;
            border: solid;
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: top;

        }

        /* Highlight the "current" day */

        .days td .active {
            padding: 3px;
            background: #1abc9c;
            color: white !important
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Banner -->
    <div class="intro-wrapper">
        <section id="intro">
            <p></p>

            <h2>Manage your Schedule</h2>
            <p>Add. Share. And Enjoy!</p>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="form-wrapper">
        <section id="one">
            <div class="form-start">
                <header>
                    <h2>Add an Event</h2>
                </header>
                <form method="post" id="form">
                    <div>
                        <label for="date">Date</label>
                        <br>
                        <input name="date" id="date" type="date">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <label for="who">With Whom?</label>
                        <br>
                        <input name="who" id="who" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <label for="remarks">Remarks</label>
                        <br>
                        <textarea name="remarks" id="remarks" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input value="Add Event" type="submit" id="event-adder-button">
                    </li>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <!--end of Form-->

    <!-- Calendar -->
    <section class="calendar-wrapper">
        <div class="inner">
            <h2>Calendar</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="month">
            <ul>
                <li class="prev">&#10094;</li>
                <li class="next">&#10095;</li>
                <li>October
                    <br>
                    <span style="font-size:18px">2018</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table class="calendar-table">
                <tr class="weekdays">
                    <th>Mo</th>
                    <th>Tu</th>
                    <th>We</th>
                    <th>Th</th>
                    <th>Fr</th>
                    <th>Sa</th>
                    <th>Su</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="days">
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">1</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">2</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">3</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">4</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">5</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">6</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">7</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="days">
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">8</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">9</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber active">
                        10
                    </span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">11</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">12</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">13</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">14</span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="days">
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">15</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">16</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">17</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">18</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">19</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">20</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">21</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="days">
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">22</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">23</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">24</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">25</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">26</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">27</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">28</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="days">
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">29</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">30</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber">31</span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber"></span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber"></span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber"></span></td>
                    <td><span class="dayNumber"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script>
        const dateInput = document.getElementById('date');
        const nameInput = document.getElementById('who');
        const remarksInput = document.getElementById('remarks');
        const eventAdderButton = document.getElementById('event-adder-button');
        const calendar = document.getElementsByClassName('days');

        eventAdderButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const date = dateInput.value.split('-'); // Split date string
            // Parse as string so == works for string to number;
            const year = parseInt(date[0]);
            const month = parseInt(date[1]);
            const day = parseInt(date[2]);
            console.log('Adder clicked: ', date);
            console.log('Adder day: ', day);
            console.log('Calendar Days: ', calendar);
            for (let i = 0; i < calendar.length; i++) {
                const calendardays = calendar[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                for (let j = 0; j < calendardays.length; j++) {
                    const dayNumber = calendardays[j].getElementsByClassName('dayNumber'); 
                    // DayNumber is an array with single element from span.dayNumber, 
                    // >  this keeps the day comparison easy and consistent.
                    if (dayNumber[0].textContent == day) {
                        const newEvent = document.createElement('p');
                        newEvent.textContent = `${remarksInput.value}:  ${nameInput.value}`;
                        // > Changed the below line, kept it as reference.
                        // calendardays[j].innerHTML = "<p>" + calendardays[j] + "</p>" + newEvent.innerHTML;
                        calendardays[j].appendChild(newEvent);
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        const form = document.getElementById("form");
        form.addEventListener("submit", formSubmitted, true);
        // Prevent the form from submitting!
        function formSubmitted(e) {
            console.log('formSubmitted! ', e);
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Result**
The event is added to calendar
[image]

**Note:**
Sorry for not posting a snippet, can't do that yet... :)