# JQuery $.Wrap() redirect to action page

Tags: jquery

I have this simple wrap, bind to onClick

HTML

```
<button class="button secondary" onclick="editButton(this)">Edit</button>
```

JQuery

```
function editButton(edit) {
var row = $(edit).closest('.row'),
    cells = row.children().toArray(),
    i=0, 
    inputName = "",
    inputValue = "", 
    html = "";

cells.pop(); // remove control cell

for(i; i<cells.length; i++) {
    inputName = $(cells[i]).attr('data-name');
    inputValue = $(cells[i]).attr('data-value');
    html = "<input type='text' name='"+inputName+"' value='"+inputValue+"'>";
    $(cells[i]).html(html);
}

$(row).wrap('<form action="/action_page.php" method="post"></form>');
$(row).wrap('<div class="test"></div>'); //this works!
```

}

instead of wrapping the dom, the page refresh to action_page.php

Comment: That's because the `<button>` submits the form, causing it to be redirected to whatever that is specified in the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element. Use either `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` to avoid this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an HTML button not reload the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

you need to stop the event

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <button class="button secondary" onclick="editButton(event, this)">Edit</button>

    </div>

</div>

<script>
function editButton(e, edit) {
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();

    var row = $(edit).closest('.row');
    $(row).wrap( '<form method="post" action="/action_page.php"></form>');
    $(row).wrap('<div class="test"></div>'); //this works!

    console.log( 'done');

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized I need to declare a button type, without declaration, it defaulted to `type=submit`;

```
<button class="button button secondary" onclick="editButton(this)">Edit</button>
```

Comment: that is a great point aahhaa, including the type="button" attribute negates the need for preventDefault & stopPropagation ...