# How to update an array of size X using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to run this script, it updates my array for a second, but it seems that after the function runs, the document returns to normal.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="add_value()"/>
</form>


<script>    
    var array = ["1", "2", "3"];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array[3];

    function add_value() {
        array.push("69");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array[3];
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = array[3];
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, outside of your function, `array[3]` doesn't exist, so there would be an error.

Comment: @JackBashford It would evaluate to `undefined`, not be an error iirc.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it seems that after the function runs, the document returns to normal"? What is the exact behavior you're seeing in relation to before and after the button press?

Comment: As explained above `array[3]` does not exist. Array index will start from **0** so `array[2]` will return the third item in the `array` and `array[0]` will return the first item in the `array`

Comment: @JackBashford how would i make array[3] exist outside the function? I want to push a button to add an entry to the array and update the demo paragraph

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an HTML button not reload the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have an input of type submit, the browser reloads the page after you press the button.

Instead use

```
<input type="button"
```