# Pressing the enter key while input is focused causes screen to go blank

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the long title, but I really can't think of another way to word it. I've searched similar posts but all I'm finding is posts about how to use `keyup()`. I'm already using that, my problem is the blank screen.

#### Problem

The problem I've encountered is that everything runs correctly if you click on the submit button, but if you press the enter key while the input is focused, the screen just goes blank.

#### Attempted Solution

To remedy this I attempted to set a `keyup()` function to preventDefault and trigger the button click.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if ($("#bday").is(":focus") && e.key == "Enter") {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#submit').click();
    }
});
```

---

## Summary

#### Steps to Reproduce

- Type date in input field
- Press the enter key (on your keyboard)

#### Expected Behavior

Should be the same as when submit button is clicked with mouse.

#### Actual Behavior

Upon pressing the enter key, the screen goes blank.

#### Conclusion

I see that the enter key is indeed triggering a click on the submit button, but the screen still goes blank anyway. Is my `keyup()` function set up wrong or am I missing something else entirely? There's no console error to tip me off so I'm clueless.

---

#### Snippet

```js
// Keyup
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if ($("#bday").is(":focus") && e.key == "Enter") {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#submit').click();
    }
});

// Input Mask
$("#bday").inputmask({ mask: "99-99-9999" });

// Logic
$("#submit").click(function() {
  // Icons
  var arrow = $(".divider>.fa-arrow-right");
  var x = $(".divider>.fa-times");
  
  // Warnings
  var warning = "<span class='input-warning'>Invalid input. Please try again.</span>"
  
  // Birthday ranges
  var date1 = "1930-01-01";
  var date2 = "1940-01-01";
  var date3 = "1950-01-01";
  var date4 = "1960-01-01";

  // Enrollment period beginnings
  var enp1 = "[date 1 goes here]";
  var enp2 = "[date 2 goes here]";
  var enp3 = "[date 3 goes here]";
  var enp4 = "[date 4 goes here]";

  // Get user input
  var date = $("#bday")
    .val()
    .split("-");

  // Covert date format
  var newDate = date[2] + "-" + date[0] + "-" + date[1];
  console.log(date);
  console.log(newDate);

  // Check for undefined variable
  if ($('#bday').val() === "") {
    $('#app-container').append(warning);
    return false;
  } else {
    $('.input-warning').hide();
    
    // Date comparison
    if (newDate <= date1) {
      $("#enrollment").text("Your enrollment period began a looooong time ago");
      arrow.hide();
      x.fadeIn();
    } else if (newDate >= date1 && newDate <= date2) {
      x.hide();
      arrow.fadeIn().animate({ marginLeft: 0 });
      $("#enrollment").text("Your enrollment period begins on " + enp1);
    } else if (newDate >= date2 && newDate <= date3) {
      x.hide();
      arrow.fadeIn().animate({ marginLeft: 0 });
      $("#enrollment").text("Your enrollment period begins on " + enp2);
    } else if (newDate >= date3 && newDate <= date4) {
      x.hide();
      arrow.fadeIn().animate({ marginLeft: 0 });
      $("#enrollment").text("Your enrollment period begins on " + enp3);
      // For some reason the condition below is firing even though newDate is undefined
    } else if (newDate >= date4) {
      arrow.hide();
      x.fadeIn();
      $("#enrollment").text("Millenials aren't elegible for medicare, silly").fadeIn(500);
    } else {
      arrow.hide();
      x.fadeIn();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
::placeholder {
  color: graytext;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: #2780bc;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#app-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  display: grid;
  grid: 1fr 35px / 1fr 100px 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

#form-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-column: 1;
  border: 2px solid #ececec;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#form-wrapper form {
  display: grid;
  grid: auto / 1fr;
  width: 210px;
}
#form-wrapper #bday {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39), 0 -1px 1px #fff, 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
#form-wrapper #submit {
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2780bc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.divider {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 2;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.divider .fa-arrow-right {
  display: none;
  color: green;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.divider .fa-times {
  display: none;
  color: indianred;
  font-size: 3em;
}

#output {
  display: grid;
  grid: 80px 1fr / 1fr;
  align-items: start;
  grid-column: 3;
  border: 2px solid #ececec;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#output h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#output #enrollment {
  display: none;
}

.input-warning {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  border: 2px solid indianred;
  color: indianred;
  width: 250px;
  justify-self: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="app-container">
  <div id="form-wrapper">
    <h2 class="text" value="title">Enter your birthday</h2>
    <br>
    <form>
      <input id="bday" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" name="bday" type="text"/>
      <br>
      <button id="submit" type="button">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
  <div id="output">
    <h2>Your medicare enrollment period begins:</h2>
    <span id="enrollment"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is this form dynamic?  It would be simpler to handle the `keyup` event for the input, rather than the document.

Comment: That's true, I'll fix that later. It's not really my concern at them moment.

Comment: This should not be marked as a duplicate and this is why. I was googling a symptom that I was experiencing. I didn't realize it was reloading the page at first. Many developers, especially new ones like myself don't always know exactly why something is breaking. This post should be left up to help point people toward the correct answer so that they don't ask the same question again when looking for the same symptom.

Comment: The post is still here.  It's linked to the previous question that you yourself linked.  Anyone finding the correct post will find their answer.  Anyone finding this will have both this *and* the post you linked.  This is a duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my answer here [How do I make an HTML button not reload the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page)

I used a `<button>` so that clicking on the submit button wouldn't refresh the page, but apparently Chrome will refresh anyway if the `<button>` is inside a `<form>`. I changed the `<form>` to a `<div>` and it no longer refreshes when I press enter.

Comment: Well, that's an interesting downvote since this is literally the answer to my question lol.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if ($("#bday").is(":focus") && e.which == 13) { // 13 is the keycode for Enter
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#submit').click();
    }
});
```

The reason for blank screen is you are submitting a form to self.
Any input inside the form is going to be submitted, while pressing enter.

Comment: So how can I submit the input to my jQuery function and not have a blank screen appear?

Comment: return false from a function until the date is correct, returning false prevents the form from submitting.

Comment: I don't think you actually looked a my code...I'm using a `<button>` element so that it won't submit. But I figured it out. Answer is above.