# Why is my button that calls a function on click making my page reload

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working on a form that uses javascript to create a paragraph. For some reason, when I click my button, it forces my page to reload. Could you anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
console.log('everything is linked')
function createParagraph() {
    console.log('function called');
    var wordOne=document.getElementById('textOne').value
    var wordTwo=document.getElementById('testTwo').value

    var paragraph = '<p>My first word is' + wordOne+'. My Second word is '+ wordTwo+'.</p>';

    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML= paragraph
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input id='textOne' type="text">
        <input id='textTwo' type="text">
        <button onclick="createParagraph()">Click Me</button>
    </form>
    
    <div id="answer"></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make an HTML button not reload the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of a `<button>` inside a `<form>` is to submit that form.  Set the button's `type` to explicitly not be a "submit":

```
<button type="button" onclick="createParagraph()">Click Me</button>
```

Additionally, if you have no use for the actual `<form>` (don't want to submit it) then it's probably best to just remove it:

```
<body>
    <input id='textOne' type="text">
    <input id='textTwo' type="text">
    <button type="button" onclick="createParagraph()">Click Me</button>
    
    <div id="answer"></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

That way there's nothing to accidentally be submitted in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your button acts as a submit button, so your form is being submitted. To prevent this, you can use attribute onSubmit on your form and prevent sending form.

```
<form onSubmit="return false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the button is in a form and the form is probably submitted.

add the `type="button"` to not submit the form.

```js
console.log('everything is linked')
function createParagraph() {
    console.log('function called');
    var wordOne=document.getElementById('textOne').value
    var wordTwo=document.getElementById('testTwo').value

    var paragraph = '<p>My first word is' + wordOne+'. My Second word is '+ wordTwo+'.</p>';

    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML= paragraph
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input id='textOne' type="text">
        <input id='textTwo' type="text">
        <button type="button" onclick="createParagraph()">Click Me</button>
    </form>
    
    <div id="answer"></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```