# Javascript: Avoid refreshing page after submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

my knowledge in Javascript is basic.
I'm trying to run a function when clicking the button submit, but when I do the page shows for a fraction of a second the result in the webpage but then it refreshes automatically showing the page in blank again. Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

HTML

```html
    <section class="container-form">
        <div>
            <p>
                Por favor ingresar los datos de tu préstamo para hacer el cálculo.
            </p>
        </div>
        <form action="" id="form">
            <input type="number" name="capital" id="capital" placeholder="Capital Inicial $">
            <input type="number" name="rate" id="rate" placeholder="Tasa de Interés Anual %">
            <input type="number" name="periods" id="periods" placeholder="Cantidad de cuotas">
            <div>
                <label for="frequency">Frecuencia de las cuotas</label>
                <select name="frequency" id="frequency">
                    <option value="monthly">Mensual</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="container-btn">
                <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="submit" onclick="calculateAnnuity()">
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>

    <section class="container-table">
        <table id="table-results" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nº</th>
                    <th>Cuota</th>
                    <th>Interés</th>
                    <th>Capital</th>
                    <th>Saldo</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
```

JS

```js
// Declarar variables
let capital;
let rate;
let frequency;
let periods;
let btnSubmit;
let tableResults;

// Asignar valores a variables desde el form
capital = document.getElementById('capital');
rate = document.getElementById('rate');
frequency = document.getElementById('frequency');
periods = document.getElementById('periods');
btnSubmit = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
tableResults = document.querySelector('#table-results tbody')

// Disparador de funcións
/* btnSubmit.addEventListener('click',() => {
    calculateAnnuity(capital.value, rate.value, frequency.value, periods.value)
}) */

function calculateAnnuity (capital, rate, frequency, periods) {
    // Declarar variables
    let annuity = 0;
    let actualCapital = capital;
    let interestFee = 0;
    let capitalFee = 0;

    // Calculo de cuota
    annuity = capital * (rate/100/12)
                        /
                        (1-Math.pow(1+rate/100/12,-periods));

    console.log(typeof(capital)+" "+typeof(rate)+" "+typeof(periods)+" "+typeof(annuity))

    
    for(let i = 0; i <= periods; i++) {

        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = `
            <td>${i}</td>
            <td>${parseFloat(annuity).toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>${parseFloat(interestFee).toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>${parseFloat(capitalFee).toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>${parseFloat(actualCapital).toFixed(2)}</td>
        `
        switch (frequency) {
            case 'monthly':
                interestFee = actualCapital * rate/100/12;
            default:
                continue;
        }

        capitalFee = annuity - interestFee;
        actualCapital = actualCapital - capitalFee;

        console.log(actualCapital);

        tableResults.appendChild(row)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Use <input type="button" instead of <input type="submit". Type will make the page reload.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make an HTML button not reload the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

Form events comes with `event` or just `e` for intimates.
at your form action in javascript, you can use **e.preventDefault();** function, to prevents browser to refresh when form is submited.

Comment: Use it how?....