# How to close popup without reload page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a circle after clicking on which a popup appears . This popup has a button to close it. But it doesn't work the way I want it to. I want the popup to close but not reload the page.

I tried using onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.remove(); return false;" . But it doesn't work correctly. Please tell me how to do it!

HTML:

```
<main>
    <div class="button">
        <input onclick="check()" type="checkbox" name="popup__input" id="popup__input" class="popup__check">
    </div>
    <div class="popup" name="popup" id="popup">
        <label class="popup__label">
            <form>
                <div class="form__input">
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
                </div>
                <button class="form__button" type="submit" form="nameform" value="Submit">Відправити</button>
                <div class="close-button__container">
                    <button class="close__button">&times;</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
    </main>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
    position: absolute;
    grid-area: "c";
    transition: linear 4s;
}
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 40px 0;
    font-size: 60px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
form {
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
    "a"
    "b"
    "c";
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}
.form__input{
    display: grid;
    grid-area: "b";
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 12;
    
}
.close__button{
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgba(104, 99, 99, 0);
    grid-column-start: 12;
    grid-column-end: 12;
}
.close-button__container{
    display: grid;
    grid-area: "a";
    place-items: start middle;
}
.form__button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:#2962d3;
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 11;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.form__button:hover {
    background-color: #4a79d6;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 850px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(104, 99, 99, 0.5);
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: end;
}

.popup__label {
    
}

.popup__check {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}



@media (max-width: 1024.98px) {
    .button {
        width:80px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
        position: absolute;
        transition: linear 4s;
      }
}
@media (max-width: 890.98px) {
    .popup {
        width: 750px;
    }
    .form__button {
        width: 500px;
        height: 45px;
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-column-end: 6;
    }
    
}
@media (max-width: 768.98px) {
    input[type=text], select {
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 50px 0;
        font-size: 40px;
        display: flex;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .form__button {
        width: 100%;
        height: 45px;
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-column-end: 11;
        margin-top: 125px;
    }
    .popup {
        width: 600px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 620.98px) {
    .popup {
        width: 480px;
    }
    input[type=text], select {
        height: 50px;
    }
    .form__button {
        height: 35px;
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-column-end: 11;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .close__button{
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 507.98px) {
    input[type=text], select {
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 45px 0;
    }
    .popup {
        width: 330px;
    }
    .close__button{
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 400.98px) {
    .form__button {
        height: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 15px;
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-column-end: 11;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    .popup {
        width: 350px;
        height: 150px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 358.98px) {
    input[type=text], select {
        height: 30px;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 35px 0px;
    }
    .form__button {
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .popup {
        width: 280px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    .close__button{
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 300.98px) {
    input[type=text], select {
        width: 200px;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 35px 0px;
        font-size: 20px;
        display: flex;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .form__button {
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .popup {
        width: 240px;
        height: 150px;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
let elem = document.querySelector('.button');

function check() {
    const popup = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');
    if (document.getElementById('popup__input').checked = true) {
      for (var i=0;i<popup.length;i+=1){
        popup[i].style.display = 'block';
      }
    } else {
      popup.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  
  const changePosition = () => {
    let randX = Math.random();
    let randY = Math.random();
    const circleSize = {
      width: elem.clientWidth,
      heigth: elem.clientHeight
    };
  
    const windowWidth = window.innerWidth - circleSize.width;
    const windowheigth = window.innerHeight - circleSize.heigth;
  
    let randXMult = windowheigth * randX;
    let randXP = randXMult + 'px';
    let randYMult = windowWidth * randY;
    let randYP = randYMult + 'px';
  
  
    elem.style.top = randXP;
    elem.style.left = randYP;
  };
  
  
  
  setInterval(changePosition, 1000);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make an HTML button not reload the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the type of button on the close icon as `button` and give the `button` an id of `close__button` so that we can select with javascript.

`<button id="close__button" type="button" class="close__button">&times;</button>`

Grab the button and add a `click` event listener:

```js
const close_button = document.getElementById('close__button').addEventListener('click', close);
  
function close() {
    const popup = document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
}
```